# How to convert multidimensional array to string in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to convert multidimensional array to string in PHP. For example, I have two arrays like array('540'),array('520').These two arrays are in a common array. I want to get the result as a string like '540,520'. I tried like the following and output is Array,Array. Implode function is not working because it is a multidimensional array.

```
$ids = array(array('540'),array('520'));
for($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++){
    $CT_IDS[] = $ids[$i];
}
echo implode(',',$CT_IDS);
```

How I get 540 and 520 as string output?

Comment: Try `$CT_IDS[] = $ids[$i][0];` instead inside the for loop. That should do it.

Comment: What exactly is the result supposed to be? For what purpose? What about more nested arrays? What about arrays with more entries? Does the nested-ness need to be preserved in the string or not?

Comment: If you want to do this to arbitrary depth, it will need to be recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ids = array(array('540'),array('520'));
for($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++){
    $CT_IDS[] = implode(",",$ids[$i]);
}
echo implode(',',$CT_IDS);
```

Comment: Use this one line code : `implode(", ",array_map(function($a) { return '<a href="'.$a['slug'].'">'.$a['name'].'</a>'; }, $your_array) );`

Answer (score 7):

No loops:

```
$ids = array(array('540'),array('520'));
print implode(',', array_map('reset', $ids));
// 540,520
```

Comment: Sweet and simple.. This should be the accepted answer, according to me, because of 1 simple reason => "No loops"..

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple:

```
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $CT_IDS[] = $id[0];
}
echo implode(',', $CT_IDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$arr = array();
foreach($ids as $id) {
   $arr[] = $id[0]; 
}
echo implode(',', $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$ids = array(array('540'),array('520'));


$CT_IDS = array();

foreach($ids as $val)
{
    foreach($val as $values)
    {
        $CT_IDS[] = $values;
    }   
}
echo implode(',',$CT_IDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your case;

```
$ids = array(array(0=> '540'),array(0 =>'520'));
$CT_IDS = array();
foreach ($ids as $new_arr) $CT_IDS[] = $new_arr[0]; //get the data 
echo $out = implode(', ', $CT_IDS); //and implode the output
```